# Console window keeps closing, even after I type in other statements

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to programming and as seems to be traditional I tried to create a "hello world" program in C#; however, as soon as I run the program it closes.

This is my code inside:

```
main()

    console.writeline("hello world");
    console.writeline("enter name");
    console.writeline("where is the frikin console");
```

It's really annoying and I know it might be something simple for the additional users but how do I keep the window open.

Comment: Try running as `Ctrl + F5` ! !

Comment: @V4Vendetta: This simply starts the application without attaching the debugger... doesn't help at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really quite simple.

After this line of code:

```
Console.WriteLine("where is the frikin console");
```

You need to add this:

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

That should work.

The reason the console closes is because you told it to write some stuff to the screen, after it has finished writing what you told it to write it simply closes itself all in the fraction of a second. if you add `Console.ReadLine`, the console will wait for you to input something before closing, like pressing a key on the keyboard.

Comment: You said its simple, and you made mistake in it. Read what changes I have made.

Comment: I am sorry but i don't see any changes you made to my comment..? I am new here am i missing something?

Comment: Ooh Thanks everyone that worked, and thanks for explaining why it closed. And it seems stack overflow is far more helpful(it takes donkeys years on YA sometimes) than Google for solving problems, cheers anyway.

Comment: @davidallan Nikhil corrected your character casing (e.g. Console instead of console) ... you can see changes when you click on "... ago" behind "edited".

Comment: Ironically, @NikhilAgrawal didn't notice that WriteLine was also incorrectly cased...

Answer (score 2):

Use `Console.ReadLine();` or `Console.ReadKey();` at the end of your program to wait for the return key or for any key.

Answer (score 2):

You can build your program and run the exe from the command line, that will allow you to see the output.

If you want the program to remain running then adding the Read() statement is the traditional approach, as others have already said.

If you just want to see it in debugging and do not want or need the read statement then place a breakpoint at the end of the program during a debug session.

Comment: +1 A breakpoint is how I would do it too. Who wants to have unnecessary ReadLines in their code?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding Console.Read(). You need to pause execution somehow.

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine("hello world");
Console.WriteLine("enter name");
Console.WriteLine("where is the frikin console");
Console.ReadLine();
```

`Console.ReadLine();` will close the console after you've hit (for example) enter.
`Console.ReadKey();` will close the console after the next key-hit

You can read the console-contents with these methods,too

```
Console.WriteLine("hello world");
Console.WriteLine("enter name");
string name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Your name is: " + name);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

add below line at the end

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CTRL` + `F5` which will opens the command line and after execution of your code, it shows `Press any key to continue...`. This will be handy for you than adding few lines of code additionally.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

in the end of your code. You are having this problem because the program just write the message then it ends, that's why you can't see anything. By adding that line, you keep the program waiting something to be typed and you can read the message. After this, type something to end the program.

Answer (score 0):

The window automatically closes after your program, you need to let it take some input, for example:

Add

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

Which takes a line of input (till "\n"). And your program will wait **until** somebody hit the return key (they can type anything and the program won't close: **until** you hit the return key. You can type in "hello world back what's up are you ok?" and nothing will happen.)

or

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

Which will take a character of input. This will make your program wait for the user to press any key and then closes.